# How to convert list of data frames (having more than 1000 data frames) to single data frame in Pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have more than 5000 dataframes in one list and I want to combine all the df into 1 df in distributed computing.

I have tried reduce function but it's taking around 2 hour to run. Is there any better way which take less time?

```
torqueFilteredRawData = [df1,df2,......,df5600]

torqueFRData = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, torqueFilteredRawData)

display(torqueFRData)
```

---

EDIT - adding details from comments

I have 2 dataframes:

- dataframe 1 have `From` and `To` timestamp columns
- dataframe 2 have all timestamp related data.

I want to query dataframe 2 to get data between `From` and `To` available in dataframe 1. I used map function to query dataframe 2 which returns a list of dataframe :

```py
startTime = SD_GE_One.select("startTime").collect() 
endTime = SD_GE_One.select("endTime").collect() 
FilteredRawData = list(map(lambda x,y:RawData.filter("SignalTimeStamp BETWEEN '"+ str(x[0])+"' AND '"+str(y[0])+"'"), startTime,endTime))
```

Comment: How many total rows are in the result?

Comment: Depending on the size of the dataframes you can write them to parquet using the append option: `df.write.mode('append').parquet('parquet_data_file')` and then reload the parquet.

Comment: why do you have so many dataframe ? probably, better than `union` all the dataframe in one, just create one unique dataframe when reading.

Comment: @john zwinck each dataframe has 120 rows

Comment: @Steven I have 2 dataframes,  dataframe 1 have "From" and "To" timestamp columns, dataframe 2 have all timestamp related data. I want to query dataframe 2 to get data between From and To available in dataframe 1.

I used map function to query dataframe 2 which returns a list of dataframe :

startTime = SD_GE_One.select("startTime").collect()

endTime = SD_GE_One.select("endTime").collect()

FilteredRawData = list(map(lambda x,y:RawData.filter("SignalTimeStamp BETWEEN '"+ str(x[0])+"' AND '"+str(y[0])+"'"), startTime,endTime))

list(FilteredRawData)

Comment: If each dataset has 120, then you can probably do it on the driver.

```
local_ torqueFilteredRawData = reduce(list.__add__, map(lambda df: df.collect(), torqueFilteredRawData))

display(spark.createDataFrame(torqueFilteredRawData))
```